# TCP Async Socket - Can not receive the data from the Server

Tags: c#

I have a code that  sends some commands  to the server by using Async messaging. But unfortunately I am unable to receive the data as a string. I mean in the console I get the message that I got a response from the server of 150 bytes. but what I need is to get the data itself in the console. Tried almost everything but was not successful. the code  is below :

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

// State object for receiving data from remote device.  
public class StateObject
{
    // Size of receive buffer.  
    public const int BufferSize = 256;

    // Receive buffer.  
    public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];

    // Received data string.  
    public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    // Client socket.  
    public Socket workSocket;
}

public class AsynchronousClient
{
    // The port number for the remote device.  
    private const int port = 5002;

    // ManualResetEvent instances signal completion.  
    private static readonly ManualResetEvent connectDone =
        new ManualResetEvent(false);

    private static readonly ManualResetEvent sendDone =
        new ManualResetEvent(false);

    private static readonly ManualResetEvent receiveDone =
        new ManualResetEvent(false);

    // The response from the remote device.  
    private static string response = string.Empty;

    public static void StartClient()
    {
        // Connect to a remote device.  
        try
        {
            // Establish the remote endpoint for the socket.  
            // The name of the   
            // remote device is "host.contoso.com".
            var ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("localhost");
            var remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);

            // Create a TCP/IP socket.  
            var client = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily,
                SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            // Connect to the remote endpoint.  
            client.BeginConnect(remoteEP,
                ConnectCallback, client);
            connectDone.WaitOne();
            var data =
               "<XCOM sid=\"A813833FF8E8EF0122B8313265538126\"> <XREQ name=\"NOP\"/> </XCOM>";
            data += '\0';
            // Send test data to the remote device.  
            Send(client, data);
            sendDone.WaitOne();

            // Receive the response from the remote device.  
            Receive(client);
            receiveDone.WaitOne();

            // Write the response to the console.  

                       Console.WriteLine("Response received : {0}", response);

            // Release the socket.  
            client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            client.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    private static void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the socket from the state object.  
            var client = (Socket) ar.AsyncState;

            // Complete the connection.  
            client.EndConnect(ar);

            Console.WriteLine("Socket connected to {0}",
                client.RemoteEndPoint);

            // Signal that the connection has been made.  
            connectDone.Set();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    private static void Receive(Socket client)
    {
        try
        {
            // Create the state object.  
            var state = new StateObject();
            state.workSocket = client;

            // Begin receiving the data from the remote device.  
            client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                ReceiveCallback, state);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    private static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Receieve Call Back Invoked");

            StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
            Socket client = state.workSocket;

            // Read data from the remote device.
            int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);
            Console.WriteLine("Receieve End Receieve");
            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                // There might be more data, so store the data received so far.
                state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));
                Console.WriteLine("Read : " + bytesRead.ToString());
                // Get the rest of the data.
                client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                    new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
                Console.WriteLine("Begin Receieve completed");
            }
            else
            {
                // All the data has arrived; put it in response.
                if (state.sb.Length > 1)
                {
                    response = state.sb.ToString();
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Received data from client");
                // Signal that all bytes have been received.
                receiveDone.Set();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("completed receive callback");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    private static void Send(Socket client, string data)
    {
        // Convert the string data to byte data using ASCII encoding.  
        var byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

        // Begin sending the data to the remote device.  
        client.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,
            SendCallback, client);
    }

    private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the socket from the state object.  
            var client = (Socket) ar.AsyncState;

            // Complete sending the data to the remote device.  
            var bytesSent = client.EndSend(ar);
            Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to server.", bytesSent);

            // Signal that all bytes have been sent.  
            sendDone.Set();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using async, but use it in a sync way? `connectDone.WaitOne();` What are the benefits of this? Also, you don't check how many bytes are sent in the Send method. If the `bytesRead` in the ReceiveCallback is 0, it means that the socket is closed.

Comment: TCP is a *continuous* stream of bytes. `Read` always either waits for at least one byte to be available and gives you those bytes or waits for the socket to close and *then* returns `0`. TCP does *not* do messaging, and this is where so many people often trip up.

Comment: but there is more than 0 bytes and server sends some output actually I see it. you mean it is not possible to show that response in the client console ?

Comment: It's not possible to detect "end of message" as opposed to "end of stream" by waiting for `Read` to return 0 bytes - but that's what you code is written to try to do. (And as I say, TCP doesn't do messaging, so if you want to write *something* the detects "end of message", it's up to you first to decide how to determine message boundaries when dealing with a *continuous* stream of bytes)